# Confusion in HTML tags

Tags: html, forms, tags, nav

I was wondering why to use so many HTML tags.
Just have a look below at the code where I have used a div tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
    <h2> HTML nav Tag</h2>
    <!-- nav tag starts -->
    <div>
        <a href="#">Home</a> |
        <a href="#">Interview</a> |
        <a href="#">Languages</a> |
        <a href="#">Data Structure</a> |
        <a href="#">Algorithm</a>
    </div>
    <!-- nav tag ends -->
</body>
 
</html>
```

It's output is:
[image]

Now if I use the nav tag instead of the div tag , I get the same output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
    <h2> HTML nav Tag</h2>
    <!-- nav tag starts -->
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a> |
        <a href="#">Interview</a> |
        <a href="#">Languages</a> |
        <a href="#">Data Structure</a> |
        <a href="#">Algorithm</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- nav tag ends -->
</body>
 
</html>
```

Output is:

[image]

If the the outputs are the same then why use nav instead of div (or why to use tags like body,main,article etc if div does the job).

Answer (score 1):

Great question. So the `<nav>` tag is identical to a `<div>` tag. A div or division tag, as you know represents a container we can use to fit content.

A nav or navigation tag has the same behavior. We use to mostly communicate with other developers the purpose and meaning of this container is to provide navigation links. It has a specialized role that is easy to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and find + understand.

So the difference is mainly to indicate semantic meaning and make it quicker to understand what is happening in a new project.

Let me know if this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

They are called Semantic markups, its purpose was to give meanings. It also improves SEO. An example is the "p" tag for paragraphs which tells the browser that the text within a "p" tag is a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Elements like `nav` and `article` are called 'Semantic' elements. When you use tags like those instead of `div`s, it is much easier to understand the meaning of that element. For example, if you see a `nav`, you will know its part of navigation. Also, using Semantic elements helps screen readers and also search engines to read the page faster.

You can learn about those here - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to ask such a question if you're still learning programming. When you advance a little bit, you'll understand the essence of having different HTML elements. Using nav tag for instance, helps to implement special styling relevant for just that, unlike using div tags instead. Go ahead and study about Bootstrap, it will help you comprehend more.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly because of semantics, navigation elements belong in nav. div is more of a general use type of tag.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav